# If $x,y,z.\geq 0$ and $x+y+z = 10$ , Then Max. value of $xyz+xy+yz +zx$,

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x,y,z.\geq 0$ and $x+y+z = 10$ , Then Maximum value of $xyz+xy+yz +zx$, is

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ First we can write the given expression

$xyz+xy+yz+zx = (x+1)(y+1)(z+1)-(x+y+z)-1 = $

$\displaystyle = (x+1)(y+1)(z+1)-\left\{(x+1)+(y+1)+(z+1)\right\}+2$.

So we can write $x+y+z = 10$ as $(x+1)+(y+1)+(z+1) = 13$

Now Let $\displaystyle (x+1)=a\geq 1\;\;,(y+1)=b\geq 1$ and $(z+1)=c\geq 1$

So expression convert into $a+b+c=13\;\;,a,b,c\geq 1$ and Maximize $abc-(a+b+c)+2$

Now How can i solve after that, Help me

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the fact that $a+b+c=13$ to say you are trying to maximize $abc-14$, which is the same as maximizing $abc$.  The AM-GM inequality now tells you that $a=b=c$

Answer (score 1):

From there: you know that $a+b+c = 13$, so it simplifies into $abc-14$. Then, since the max of the product of three numbers is if all the numbers are equal, so the max of $abc$ is $\left(\frac{13}{3}\right)^3 = \frac{2107}{27}$. So, the answer would be $\frac{2107}{27}-14 = \frac{1729}{27}$.